# Laravel Raw Bulk insert

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I wrote a function in a Controller used in the Laravel Framework. The function gets the file path of an *.csv file and then inserts all elements of this *.csv file with a raw bulk insert statement into the database. The problem is that the elements are not put in the database table when the function is executed. I do not get any errors, too. When I execute the Query in SQL Server Manager it inserts the elements without problems. What am I doing wrong and is there a better way to bulk insert the elements of an csv file to the database?

Here is the code for the function:

```
        public static function bulkInsertCSV($filePath){

            $sql = "use [testDatabase] BULK INSERT [dbo].[testTable]   
                    FROM '" . $filePath . "' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',"
                    . "ROWTERMINATOR = '\\n' );";
            //DB::statement($sql);
            DB::statement(DB::raw($sql));
        }
```

Best regards,
Yalcin

Answer (score 0):

I like using the `laravel-excel` library for dealing with my CSV files, it makes it a bit easier to manage and feels more "laravel-y" to me.

The `laravel/excel` lbirary: http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/getting-started#installation library.

What you'd then do is somewhat simple:

```
Excel::filter('chunk')->load($filePath)->chunk(500, function($rows){
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        $data = collect([]);
        foreach(App\TestTable::getFillable() as $fillable ) {
            if (isset($row[$fillable])) {
               $data->put($fillable, $row[$fillable]);
            }
        }

        App\TestTable::create($data->toArray());
    }
});
```

Notes:

- Using `chunk` ensures we don't run out of memory.
- The `getFillable()` methods assumes you defined the `protected $fillable = [];` properties on your `TestTable` model.
- The `column names` from your `testTable` match the `column names` from your `csvfile`.

Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: This would be a good solution but i forgot to say that the csv can contain up to 1.000.000 rows with a lot of columns. I already tried it with PHPExcel and it is really slow(approx 10 mins for insert operation). Your solution needed approx 7 mins. Its still too much. With BULK INSERT in SQL it takes approx 1 min. So your solution is not the one I am looking for but thanks anyway :).